# Calculate product with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning LINQ and have a very simple question that I think will help my understand the technology better. How can I find the product of an array of ints?

For example, what is the LINQ way to do:

```
int[] vals = { 1, 3, 5 };
return vals[0] * vals[1] * vals[2];
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This would work:

```
var product = vals.Aggregate(1, (acc, val) => acc * val);
```

You're starting with a seed of `1` and then the function is called for each of your values with two arguments, `acc` which is the current accumulated value, and `val` which is the value in the array; the function multiplies the current accumulated value by the value in the array and the result of that expression is passed as `acc` to the next function. i.e. the chain of function calls with the array you provided will be:

```
(1, 1) => 1
(1, 3) => 3
(3, 5) => 15
```

Comment: Use of var is a personal/team decision. Personally I don't think type information is tremendously useful, and distracts you from the *purpose* of the code. I wrote about this here: http://gregbeech.com/blogs/tech/archive/2008/03/24/to-var-or-not-to-var-implicit-typing-is-the-question.aspx

Comment: So this is how Aggregate works. This seems incredibly useful, I can't believe I haven't learnt how to do this before.

Comment: I don't think you need the seed. If no seed is provided `Aggregate` will use the first two items on the list.

Comment: The blog post mentioned in a previous comment has moved to http://gregbee.ch/blog/to-var-or-not-to-var-implicit-typing-is-the-question

Comment: @Juan The no-seed version will throw exception for empty source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ff1369203d6036a4