# C# how do I use a partially filled array in a method?

Tags: c#, arrays

My instructor wants us to create an array of 10 elements and then fill it with random numbers using console input and then multiply all the numbers together to get the product.  I can't figure out how to pass the array to a method and then successfully get the product.  Do I use a for loop?  I don't think I can use a foreach loop because it could be partially filled.  How do I even pass the array to the method in the first place?

Here's what I have so far to store the values in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{

    bool valid = false;
    do
    {
         Write("Enter an integer value or 0 to stop ");
         string input = ReadLine();
         valid = int.TryParse(input, out userInput);
    } while (!valid);

    if (userInput == 0)
    {
         break;
    }
    array[i] = userInput;
}

product = p.ArrayProduct(array.Length);
```

Comment: You can pass arrays like any other objects. In C# the array length information is carried by the array itself, so you don't need to pass the length in an extra parameter (this is a difference to C). A call could simply look like `product = mutiplyElems(array);`. You may also look into what linq can do for you, but it's a little cryptic for a beginner.

Comment: To deal with a **partially** used array you'd have to create separate variable to track how many items were entered by the user.  Then you'd have to pass that value along with the array to any methods that do the processing so they know how many slots of the array to use.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you really should be using a `List<int>` instead of a `int[]`, that will grow as new items are added.

Comment: as a side note, storing the numbers in a collection is not needed to get the product, but the assignment seems to be to get you familiar with the basics  of arrays (even that they are rarely used in high-level C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of tracking the number of entries in a separate variable and passing that to the processing function along with the array:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int SIZE = 10;
    int numEntries = 0;
    int[] array = new int[SIZE];

    Console.WriteLine("Enter up to " + SIZE.ToString() + " integer(s).");

    string input;
    int userInput;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter integer #" + (i+1).ToString() + " or 0 to stop: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            valid = int.TryParse(input, out userInput);
            if (!valid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry!");
            }
        } while (!valid);

        if (userInput == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        numEntries++;
        array[i] = userInput;
    }

    if (numEntries > 0)
    {
        int product = ArrayProduct(array, numEntries);
        Console.WriteLine("The product is " + product.ToString("n0") + ".");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No entries were made!");
    }

    Console.Write("Press [Enter] to quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static int ArrayProduct(int[] arr, int length)
{
    int product = 1;
    if (length <= arr.Length)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            product = product * arr[i];
        }
    }
    return product;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method for multiplying is as below:

```
public int ArrayProduct(int[] array)
{
   int p = 1;
   for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
   {
       p *= array[i];
   }
   return p;
}
```

You can multiply in `foreach` loop as well:

```
public int ArrayProduct(int[] array)
{
   int p = 1;
   foreach(int element in array)
   {
       p *= element;
   }
   return p;
}
```

Or you can use `Array` class like below:

```
public int ArrayProduct(int[] array)
{
    int p = 1;
    Array.ForEach(array, el =>
    {
        p *= el;
    });
    return p;
}
```

There is another extension method for arrays called, gues how! `ForEach`

```
public int ArrayProduct(int[] array)
{
    int p = 1;
    array.ForEach(element =>
    {
        p *= element;
    });
    return p;
}
```

Then you call it after you have the data as below:

```
int product = ArrayProduct(array);
Console.WriteLine(product);
```

There is another way as @Peter A. Schneider said by using `Linq` according this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252333/calculate-product-with-linq/252343#252343)

```
public int ArrayProduct(int[] array)
{
    return array.Aggregate(1, (acc, val) => acc * val);
}
```

better in `c# 6` and above:

```
public int ArrayProduct(int[] array) => array.Aggregate(1, (acc, val) => acc * val);
```

If you have problem with getting the data please let me know!

Comment: That code is returning a value of 0 and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you set the value of `p = 1` and not 0 ? or maybe you have entered a value `0` which will make the result equals to 0 by multiplying

Comment: @EvanGlassford you can change `p *= el;` to `if (el != 0) p *= el;`

Comment: @Slai But that would not compute the product of the array elements any longer ;-).

Comment: To be complete, you could mention `array.Aggregate(1, (acc, val) => acc * val);` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/252343/3150802.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider very true, but for this case 0 is the end of the array `"Enter an integer value or 0 to stop "`. I had an urge to post a LINQ answer too, but his teacher might not be happy with it :] `array.Where(i => i != 0).Aggregate((a, i) => a * i);`

Comment: Ah I see now that some array elements may still be default, i.e. 0; and also that 0 is not a possible user input. Yes, the multiplication code has to guard against that. Better still would be to normalize the array (assign to a smaller one where all elements are "valid", or use a `List` to begin with) so that the standard enumerable extension functions can be used without surprising results.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method by reference. You should use from out and ref key word:
*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx*